# How may I store geographical data in an android database and query for it?

Tags: android, storage, gis

I want to store locations in my Android phone and be able for the application to tell me if I am inside these points&radius.

What is the best way to store many point&radius locations and efficiently query for them?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this but as a very simple approach you could store the locations as lat/long pairs and a radius and use the android.location.Location class's distanceTo method as your "hit" test?

Iterate through each pair in turn and apply the test?

see [sdk reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location))